How can I get the animation to play for preview in the VFX compositing node tree tab workspace?
The movie clip or image sequence does not show the movement of the animation frame-by-frame in the VFX compositing work space, but instead shows a still image when on play.  After pressing pause, it stops at the frame image, then:  . This was working before, but all of a sudden it is not working.
